# No user_id in signed_request on authenticated app

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am creating a Facebook app, which is also a PageTab, for some users there is no user_id in the signed_request after they have authenticated the app, but only for some users.

Since I redirect to the authentication dialog when there is no user_id, there is an infinite redirect loop for those users.

How can the user_id be empty when the user has authenticated the app? All the users are Testers. But for some it works, for some it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no user_id because the testers had not accepted their tester invitation.